# Variance Reduction Using Antithetic Variates

Tags: monte-carlo

I found this online: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antithetic_variates

For example #2, can someone please provide step by step procedure on how to answer the integral using antithetic variates?

I know I need to produce a random sample from uniform distribution but after that not sure what is next.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For example 2, we  are aiming to find an approximation for  $I= \int_0^{1} \frac{1}{1+x}dx$. To this aim we will do the following:

Let $U$ be a uniform distribution defined as  $U \sim [0,1]$. Then the we have the pdf of $U$, denoted $g$ , is defined as follows: $$ g(x)=\begin{cases}  1  \quad x \in  [0,1] \\
 0 \qquad  elsewhere 
\end{cases} $$
Thus given $f(x)= \frac{1}{1+x}$, then $$E[f(U)]=\int_0^{1} f(x) g(x)dx=\int_0^{1} \frac{1}{1+x} dx  $$
Thus using this above equality we are able to estimate  $I$ by estimating the expectation. Taking a sample $\{ x_i\}_{i=1,..,n}$ of $n$ points in $[0,1]$, then $I$ can be estimated by  $$ I \approx  \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{1+x_i} $$